# Calculating density of a liquid based off 2 pressure readings at a known distance

Tags: pressure, density

I'm working on a project at home where I want to track the change in the density of a liquid over time (as it converts sugars to alcohol) using 2 submerged pressure sensors at a known distance apart. These sensors would be wired up to a microcontroller that performs the calculations. Ideally, I would like to do so without knowing the depth of liquid in the vessel, as this will vary.

[image]

Is getting this information possible from these inputs, and if so, what equation would I need to use? The results need to be accurate to 1kg/m^3.

Comment: https://www.engineersedge.com/fluid_flow/relationship_depth_pressure.htm see example 1. You can also find conversions on density.

Comment: Thanks Jim that looks like exactly what I need!